# Nautilus doesn't show up in Alt+Tab bar

Tags: shortcut-keys, nautilus

Nautilus doesn't show up in the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> program icons although I have it open.

You can see Nautilus open in the back and it doesn't show up in the tab.

[image: screenshot]

What happened? How can I fix it?